# Installing Ubuntu Server on HP Proliant dl180 gen9

Tags: 16.04, server, hp

The same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/762070/442339), I am installing Ubuntu on a server, and when going to the manage partition phase, it only shows the iSCSI option, as if the disks were not detected. The solution [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/762087/442339) is restarting over and over until magically works, but really? Is that the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the Dynamic Smart Array? Via [Ubuntu Hardware Certification site](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201509-19592/):

> Testing details This system was tested with 16.04 LTS, running the
> 4.4.0-21.37 kernel.
>
> Certification notes:
>
> **HP Dynamic Smart Array**
>
> System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array disabled.
>
> To disable Dynamic Smart Array:
>
> - Press F9 to boot into RBSU
> - Navigate to System Options -> HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i and select disable
> - Go to System options -> SATA Controller options and select Legacy SATA or AHCI
> - Reboot the machine and now you will be able to install the OS. BIOS HP: U20 (UEFI)